# Check if a object exists in a array in c#

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a json-string looking like this;

```
    {
  "products": [
    {
      "location": "City 1",
      "name": null,
      "serial": "1412234-123421-1",
      "dateCreatedUtc": "2023-01-11T08:42:01Z",
      "dateLastUpdatedUtc": "2023-07-14T08:42:01Z",
      "blocked": false
    },
    {
      "name": null,
      "serial": "1412234-12333-3",
      "dateCreatedUtc": "2023-01-15T15:32:00Z",
      "dateLastUpdatedUtc": "2023-03-17T08:00:000Z",
      "blocked": false
    },
    {
      "location": "City 2",
      "name": null,
      "serial": "1412234-543332-1",
      "dateCreatedUtc": "2023-07-14T08:42:01Z",
      "dateLastUpdatedUtc": "2023-07-14T08:42:01Z",
      "blocked": false
    },
    {
      "name": null,
      "serial": "1412234-1356634-6",
      "dateCreatedUtc": "2023-09-01T08:22:00Z",
      "dateLastUpdatedUtc": "2023-10-10T08:00:00Z",
      "blocked": false
    }
  ],
  "supplyNumbers": []
}
```

I have put it in a array;

```
Root jsonArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(jsondata);
```

with correct classes and everything.

```
public class Products
{
            public string location { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string serial { get; set; }
            public string dateCreatedUtc { get; set; }
            public string dateLastUpdatedUtc { get; set; }
            public bool blocked { get; set; }
}
public class Root
{
            public List<Products> products { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see sometimes [location] is missing in the array and that throws a exception when I accessing it.
ex;

```
jsonArray.products[0].location
```

It should ofcourse, but I'd like to check if it exists but havnt found anything that I've managed to get to work.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: The code you showed produces a `Root` not a `JArray`.  If you describe the data format with a DTO, you can use attributes to control the behavior of missing properties.  If you do everything dynamically, testing existence of a property is still straightforward but you'd need to tell use the data type of the item where the property goes missing (i.e. `jsonRoot.products[0]`)   Is it a `JObject`?

Comment: Updated OP with the classes.

Comment: And yet the title still talks about JArray...

Comment: The only possible exceptions from that line of code would be the list being null or empty.  The location being not in the JSON would not result in that line throwing.

Comment: @JonSkeet, im open to suggestions as a whole since im new to json

Comment: With the code you've given, I wouldn't expect `jsonArray.producs[0].location` to throw an exception - I'd expect it to return a null reference.

Comment: my original problem is to extract the data from the json and store it into a databasetable

Comment: I have modify the answer so it check if the product has key "location" instead of check string contains location.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/Za3ila.  `jsonArray.products[i].location` does not throw an exception for i=0..3.  Please [edit] your question to share a [mcve].

Comment: are you sure that exception is in here? your example is solid as rock. it might be sending a NULL value to DB might cause exception . can you please put your exception text here for better understanding

Comment: also, what would you do as an action if its not exists? you can filter out that rows or create exception... or replace value jsonArray.products[1].location ?? "nothing";

Comment: @PowerMouse. I ran the code again now and as you have said it works as it is. Have no idea what the problem was, but it did throw a exception. Must have been a brain-fart ...

Comment: i am happy it worked out. happy coding.

Answer (score -2):

You could try following code.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

bool checkFlag= true; //initialize 
var jsonData = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString); // the string starts with '{}' so we convert to JObject
Console.WriteLine(jsonData);   //to check the jobject we get
var products = (JArray)jsonData["products"];  //You can get element inside JObject by jsonData["a"]["b"] ,but the value of "products" starts with "[]" so convert it to JArray
                                          
foreach (var product in products)
{
    var Jproduct = (JObject)product;
    if (!Jproduct.ContainsKey("location"))  //check if any product have no key named "location" set flag false;
    {
        checkFlag = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is awful and will match `{ "name": "Delivery location" }` or `{ "geolocation": false }` and then `product.location` will still throw an exception.